# Custom button title not visible on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've a custom button, it's title is visible on iPhone but not visible on iPad. That little icon and bottom border is also visible. Button action does work. Not sure why title is not showing up on iPad. How do I debug it to find out issue?

I'm running it on simulator.

Following is code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DropDownButton: UIButton {

    var bottomBorder = UIView()

    enum ImageType: String {
        case grey = "Icons/DropDown/Grey"
        case white = "Icons/DropDown/White"
        case red = "Icons/DropDown/red"

        var image: UIImage? { return UIImage(named: rawValue) }
    }

    var imageType: ImageType = .grey {
        didSet{
            setImage(imageType.image, for: [])
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Setup Bottom-Border
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        bottomBorder = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        bottomBorder.backgroundColor = .lightGreyColour
        bottomBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(bottomBorder)

        bottomBorder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true // Set Border-Strength

        self.sizeToFit()
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "Icons/DropDown/Grey"), for: [])
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-imageView!.frame.width-16, bottom: 4.0, right: 0)
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -imageView!.frame.width, bottom: 0, right: imageView!.frame.width)
        self.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        self.setTitleColor(.greyColour, for: .disabled)
    }

}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sortButton: DropDownButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.sortButton.setTitleAndColour(title: "Most Recent", titleFont: fontBody!, colour: .white)
        self.sortButton.imageType = .white
        self.sortButton.bottomBorder.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

It looks like constraints are not being accepted on iPad, attached is screenshot

[image]

Comment: How are your constraints setup on the `SortButton` in the `ViewController` class?

Comment: It's set in storyboard.

Comment: A few stupid questions, set off your use of `colour:` as a parameter. (1) Is this a typo? Or does it work that way [I understand that that's a valid way to write it but didn't think the API supported such]. (2) A `white` font/image/background color in `viewDidLoad`.... I know you say it works on iPhones, but how? (3) I take it that you see the button with the correct size, etc. on the iPad, But have you tried moving your `viewDidLoad` and `awakeFromNib` elsewhere? It "feels" odd that you [a] use a storyboard, [b] use both of these overrides, and [c] combine both constraints and frames.

Comment: setTitleAndColour is function which I use to set title, font and colour for buttons. I'm using it all over my app. Not sure how this can be issue. Frames are used for bottom border and triangle image. Whole button itself is constrained in storyboard. Can you clarify on overriding issue? I didn't get it. Yes it shows correct size on both iPhone and iPad. On iPad it shows border view and image only the title is not showing. Size is also correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `debug view hierarchy` option in `Xcode` to see the views that make up your view controller. The visual debugger will help you see where the `SortedButton` is located.

[image: debug view hierarchy]

Then you can look through your view hierarchy and find the `SortedButton` view and look at the constraints that are set on the button. You can also use the `show object inspector` and `show size inspector` buttons in the `Inspectors Panel` to see additional information about the button.

[image]

Comment: Tx. I've checked value in object inspector after debug view hierarchy and compared it with working iPhone's values. Both are exactly same. Anything else to look for?

Comment: If you use the `size inspector`, the position of the button's the `frame` and `bounds` are the same on both `iPad` and `iPhone`?  Can you show the constraints in `IB`? Its hard to say without being able to see it. Your code implies the button is the only item on the screen.

Comment: I've updated question with frame screenshot. Constraints are not being accepted on iPad. I deleted constraints and added them back but still same issue. I'm showing this view as container view on other view where I switch the content of container view after clicking on segmented controller. Not sure how to to debug it further and fix.

Comment: Try setting the device type as `iPad` in `IB` and see how the button looks. Also make sure that you do not have any constraints set based on `trait collection` or  `size class` that would apply only to an `iPhone`

Comment: You are adding constraints in both code and in `IB`. I would try removing the line `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in your custom button to start. You usually only need to disable that setting on the view your applying constraints to in code. Can you comment out the constraints in code and do them all in `IB`?

Comment: When I change device type to iPad in storyboard and run the button does show up. Also in IB I do see the button. When I change it back to iPhone and run it on iPad it again doesn't work. So it has something to do with device type and resizing? Setting self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false doesn't have any impact.

Comment: Found the problem, it was title edge inset self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -imageView!.frame.width, bottom: 0, right: imageView!.frame.width). Silly me. Thanks for all the help to pinpointing the issue.